# How to display column index number as alphabets in 2d array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list, 2d

I need to display the column index as alphabet in my program, like, c3, instead of 2,3 [ a is 0, hence c would be 2]

Comment: do you mean you want to use `c3` like `2d_array.get('c3')`? just convert c3->(2,3)

Answer (score 1):

If you're only interested in the 26 lower case characters, this would work:

```
alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
startIndex  = (2,3)
endIndex = (alph[startIndex[0]], startIndex[1])
print(endIndex[0] + str(endIndex[1]))
```